# PHP strtotime and mktime return different results

Tags: php, strtotime, mktime

I am new to the world of coding as well as php and am confused by why the `strtotime` and `mktime` functions return different results e.g.

```
$endyear = date('Y', strtotime('+5 years')); //returns 2011 - 2015
$endyear = date('Y', mktime(0,0,0,0,0,$year+5)); //returns 2011 - 2014
```

**EDIT**

The variable $year has the value of $2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using zeroes for the month and day arguments, this essentially means

```
Day 0 = Last day of the previous month
Month 0 = Last month of the previous year
```

It's all there in the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: @Phil - Thanks. I am new to PHP so I don't know how that affects dates. How does the first day and last day of the day and month affect the year?

Comment: @Peanuts Think about it. What's the last day of month prior to the last month of the year prior to 2015?

Comment: @Phil - Sorry, probably because I am noob. I don't quite follow. The last day and month would be 31 and 12 respectively.

Comment: @Peanuts Let's break it down. Start with the year 2015. The last month of the year prior to 2015 is December 2014. The last day of the month prior to this is 30 November, 2014

Comment: @Phil - So you mean to tell me if I have 0 in the day and 0 in the month this would equate to assuming the year is 2015 is December 2014 for the month and 30 November 2014 as it is the last day before December? Okay, if that's the case, how do I add 5 years to 2011? Do I do 30, 12, 2011+5?

Comment: @Peanuts Easy, use `1` for the month and day. If you're using PHP 5.3, I'd recommend using the `DateTime` class instead of `mktime()`

Comment: @Phils - Thanks. Has mktime been deprecated?

Comment: @Peanuts No. The PHP manual makes it obvious when something has been deprecated

Comment: @Phil - Sorry for my ignorance but how is DatetIime better?

Comment: @Peanuts The interfaces for dealing with dates, diffs, intervals and timezones is well defined and easy to use.